# Rewrite a url to pretty URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite url to the pretty url with query string.
Pretty url will be:

```
https://dev.agency.com/private
```

This needs to be rewritten to:

```
https://dev.agency.com/player/5d4d1ecb9d41f/?//private
```

Tried different query string condition match without any success

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$  http://dev.agency.com/?//$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: No. It is not required

Comment: No only the word coming after ?//. In this it will be /private

Comment: This will be the url   https://dev.agency.com/private 
 which needs to be internally redirected to     https://dev.agency.com/player/5d4d1ecb9d41f/?//private

Comment: This will not be particularly private, anyword can come after ?//

Comment: Anything coming after `?//` is *after a rewrite* but remember your visitors only get to see your pretty URL, which is just `https://dev.agency.com/private` so rewrite rule has to work with that only.